# Start osgi bundle using jboss as maven plugin

Tags: jboss, osgi

I am deploying a OSGI bundle in Jboss 7.1.1 by using **Jboss as maven plugin** and I am successfully deployed it into my jboss, my console shows following massege after deployment.

00:54:51,080 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1)       JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "services-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
00:54:51,110 INFO  [org.jboss.osgi.framework] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBOSGI011001: Bundle installed: testAapi:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
00:54:51,190 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 7) JBAS018562: Redeployed "services-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"

But now I dont understand **how can I start my osgi bundle automatically using the same maven plugin means jboss as maven plugin**

Means I am deploying bundle using **mvn jboss-as:deploy** and it is deployed but it is not started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: http://community.jboss.org/message/759637#759637